# A Loop I can never return from

Tags: python, for-loop

So I have been tasked with creating a Login function using an intake from a pickle file, my only issue (that I have noticed) so far is that I can never get out of the loop.

```
    for counter in range(len(Users)):
        UserN = input("Username: ")
        if UserN in Users[counter]:
            PassW = input("Password: ")
            if PassW in Users[counter]:
                print("User Authenticated")
                break
            else:
                attempt = 1
                while attempt != 4:
                    print("Password Incorrect | Attempt", attempt)
                    PassW = input("Password: ")
                    if PassW in Users[1]:
                        print("User Authenticated")
                        MainMenu()

                    else:
                        attempt = attempt + 1

                        if attempt == 4:
                            print("\nToo many attempts, you are locked out")
                            exit()
        else:
            print("\nUser not found!\n")
```

Comment: Can you share an example of what the structure of `Users` is? I assume it's a list, but are the elements strings or some other datatype?

Comment: Can you also elaborate on which loop the program is getting stuck in? You have two loops, the `for` on L1 and the `while` on L10 and both have potential conditions where they could run forever

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is authenticated, the count of the attempt will stop increasing, but the condition for the while-loop is stop is `attempt == 4`, so it will be stuck until the user has typed in the wrong password 4 times.

To fix it, either add a variable `authenticated` before the while-loop and initialize it as `False`, then set it to `True` once the user has successfully been authenticated.

```
attempt = 1
authenticated = False
while attempt != 4 and !authenticated:
    ...
    if PassW in Users[1]:
        ...
        authenticated = True
```

Or if you don't want a new variable, simply break by

```
if PassW in Users[1]:
    ...
    break
```

to break the loop

Answer (score 0):

If you the password is found, you call another function but you never exit from the loop. You should add a break statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a break statement under

```
    MainMenu()
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your code seems quite wonky.

This code assumes that the username is the first appearing in `Users`; if the second user logs in, they need to enter their name twice, the third user 3 times, and so on. If you mistype your name on your "turn", you won't be able to log in at all.

I would suggest the following structure:

- Turn your variable "Users" into a dictionary, mapping user name to password.
- Ask the user name.
- If the user name does not appear, either stop or loop (you might want to prompt to ask whether they want to try again or not, or just let them press `ctrl-D` to stop (and catch the ensuing `EOFError` or `KeyboardInterrupt` (which happens if they press `ctrl-C` instead).

Some other issues, that are not as crucial for this question but good guidelines:

- Use proper style conventions. Variable names should not start with upper case characters. Same for goes for functions. It should be `users`, `passw`, `main_menu()`.
- You really should not store passwords in a pickle file; that is obfuscation rather than security. Have a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getpass-and-getuser-in-python-password-without-echo/ for better practices.
- When you say the user is locked out, nothing actually happens. They are not really locked out; they could just try again. That means you can just create a bit that brute-forces password guesses
- Let them enter the password, with a maximum number of guesses.
- A good rule is to test for `attempt > 3` instead of `attempt == 4`. This does not make a difference here, but in larger functions, it's often good practice to make the test a bit "wider".